# How to generate schema.rb without padding

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have schema.rb generated without all the padding in the middle. This is because often the whole table definition changes when I add a column that has a longer name. Is this possible in Rails?

So instead of this:

```
t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
```

I want this:

```
t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
t.string "encrypted_password", :default => "", :null => false
t.string "reset_password_token"
```

--

The reason for this is as follows:

When a new column gets added, columns such as "default" or "null" often are re-padded to be aligned again. However this caused the diff to clutter with irrelevant line changes.

Comment: What padding? Can you post an example?

Comment: @Substantial here you go, maybe it should not be called "padding" :P

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Please describe in detail (or better yet, show) what exactly is happening to the table definition when you add columns that have a longer name.

Comment: When a new column gets added, and the name is longer, all other column need to be re-padded so things like "default" can be aligned properly. However I don't like to see all these changes in the diff, because I really only changed one column.

Comment: Got it. Upvoted. You might want to add that to the question, mentioning the cluttered diff. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: This is the method that calculates column length: [**rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb:141-146**](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/38b5e191f6ceb71fe9981f3e18455ef76ada3331/activerecord/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb#L141-L146)

Comment: @Substantial Thanks! I guess one can only monkey patch the whole method. That method is so long!